# Python - amend NULL values based on criteira

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset like below which has some missing values. What I want to acheive is, I want to fill those NA values with any of the existing value of that respective group. it doesn;t have to be a mean or mode. is there a way to achieve this?

```
group   rate   type     feat.
A       #NA      L       100 
A        2      #NA      150
A        2       M       100
B        3       M       #NA
B       #NA      M       #NA
B       #NA      M       200
B       #NA     #NA      200
C        9       H       300
C        9       H       300
```

so one example output should be like below, by amending all NULL values to any value among that respective group.

```
group   rate   type     feat.
A        2       L       100 
A        2       L       150
A        2       M       100
B        3       M       200
B        3       M       200
B        3       M       200
B        3       M       200
C        9       H       300
C        9       H       300
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't care about which value is used, you can apply [`groupby.transform('first')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) on the whole dataframe:

```
out = df.fillna(df.groupby('group').transform('first'))
```

Output:

```
  group  rate type  feat.
0     A   2.0    L  100.0
1     A   2.0    L  150.0
2     A   2.0    M  100.0
3     B   3.0    M  200.0
4     B   3.0    M  200.0
5     B   3.0    M  200.0
6     B   3.0    M  200.0
7     C   9.0    H  300.0
8     C   9.0    H  300.0
```

Comment: thank you, this worked as expected. Is there any way I could use the same code with "mode" instead of "first"?

Comment: Yes: `df.fillna(df.groupby('group').transform(lambda g: g.mode()[0]))`

Comment: But why would you specify in the question "*it doesn't have to be a mean or mode*" if the first follow-up is "*any way I could use the same code with mode?*"? ;)

Comment: I just wanted to know if those could be also an option, I have very high values in rate where it is missing, they have put 9999, so mean causes issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Fill NA values
df_filled = df.groupby('group').apply(lambda group: group.bfill().ffill())
```

Try functions bfill and ffill are used to fill the NA values.

Comment: To match OP's expected output, `ffill()` should be placed before `bfill()`